# Asus H87-PRO /usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed

Tags: 13.10, power-management, asus, bios, fancontrol

On an Asus H87-PRO:

```
$ sudo pwmconfig 
# pwmconfig revision 5857 (2010-08-22)
(...) 
/usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed
```

here's the output from $ sensors:

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +27.8°C  (crit = +97.0°C)
temp2:        +29.8°C  (crit = +97.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +40.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +92.0°C)
Core 0:         +32.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +92.0°C)
Core 1:         +33.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +92.0°C)
Core 2:         +40.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +92.0°C)
Core 3:         +31.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +92.0°C)

pkg-temp-0-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +41.0°C
```

do I need/should I try https://github.com/ambrosa/Asus-P8P67-Ubuntu-lm-sensors-driver ?

do I need some acpi_osi=... (Linux?) or acpi_enforce_resources=... (lax?) boot option?

do I need to install sensord read-edid i2c-tools on this board?

do I need to do something in the BIOS to "allow" fan control by the OS?

Answer (score 5):

Can you post the output of `sudo sensors-detect`?

Edit:  Nevermind.  I read the pastbin you linked (totally missed it).  It looks like `sensors-detect` does not fully recognize your Super I/O chip.  According to [this](http://www.hardwaresecrets.com/article/ASUS-H87-PRO-Motherboard/1841/8) the Super I/O is the Nuvoton (formerly Winbond) NCT 5538D.  The chip ID appears to be the same as the NCT6775 family.  You can download the driver from [here](https://github.com/groeck/nct6775/archive/master.tar.gz), which is a link to github of the maintainer of that kernel module (it is a download link).

Then do the following:

```
cd /path/to/directory/you/saved/the/file
tar xzvf master.tar.gz
sudo make
sudo make install
modprobe hwmon
modprobe nct6775
```

Then, check to make sure you did everything correctly:

```
lsmod | grep nct
```

The output should look something like [this][3]:

```
user@computer:/# lsmod | grep nct
nct6775                44104  0 
hwmon_vid              12388  1 nct6775
```

Then run `sudo pwmconfig` and hopefully everything should be ok.

Comment: I did this but `lsmod | grep nct` shows nothing. My board is Z97M-PLUS.

Comment: This works great! Thanks a lot. Just FTR, it actually turns out that (in 14.04 at least) this NCT6775 Module is already available in the Kernel, so just modprode is sufficient, no need to DL and make it.

Comment: Yeah, support was added to kernel 3.12, iirc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add acpi_enforce_resources=lax to the kernel command line, and to modprobe the module that `sudo sensors-detect` says to ( and iirc, offers to add to /etc/modules for you ).

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to do it (for this board).. see http://pastebin.com/Up6KFRyu for exact details. Any suggestions re. recommended next steps? (BTW, this is on Ubuntu 13.10, in case that is of any interest.)

Comment: @vorburger, coretemp is just the cpu internal temperature monitor.  It looks like your board has a Nouvaton chip that isn't yet supported, so you are out of luck, unless you feel like trying 14.04 where support may have been added.

Comment: The acpi_enforce_resources=lax does not appear to be needed or help for this specific problem.

Comment: @vorburger, I'm not sure what problem you are referring to but the original poster's problem was getting the module to control the embedded fan/thermal chip to load, and this generally requires the mentioned fix.